# Java List containing a List of different subclasses

Tags: java, list, inheritance, arraylist, subclass

I have an `Animal` class that is extended by subclasses `Duck` and `Cow` (and many more). I am making an `AnimalManager` class that handles interactions between my animals and other classes.

I am trying to have a list of lists that contain different Animal subclasses:
`List<List<differentSubclass>` in the AnimalManager class.

Example:
A List that contains a List of 100 Ducks, a List of 100 cows, a List of 50 gorillas, etc.

What are the best possible ways to create this list of lists?

Comment: List of lists is a bad approach as you will need to make a contract - index 0 - ducks, index 1 - cows instead of matching cows by "cows"

Comment: Do you think it would be better to have a separate manager class for each Animal subclass? I imagine there would be quite a bit of duplicate code if I did that.

Comment: @user3603179 I don't get your question at all. You can have an Animal common manager, and a manager for those animals you want to override some interactions of the common defined.

Comment: @ Santi Gil I meant that instead of having one manager class to handle all the animals, I would have a manager class for each animal subclass i.e. DuckManager, CowManager. I chose the former and I am storing all the animals in :ArrayList<ArrayList<? extends Animal>> animals; Do you reckon that's reasonable?

Comment: @user3603179 To choose a manager for each subclass would be a good decision if they have a distinct behaviour. If they have the same, absolutely get it all in the `Manager` parent class.

Answer (score 1):

Use `map` with relation `class` > list of animals of `class`

```
Map<Class<? extends Animal>, List<? extends Animal>> map
```

This delclaration allows you to:

```
map.put(Duck.class, new ArrayList<Duck>())
```

Comment: I guess you want to say `Map<Class<? extends Animal>, List<? extends Animal>> map`

Comment: Definitely `Animal`. Nevertheless approach is the same.

Answer (score -1):

If you know previously the size of your list of lists, I recommend you to use a simple table. You would have then more effiency and velocity that @xenteros answer. This would be something like:

```
private static final int DUCKS = 0;
private static final int COWS = 1;
private static final int GORILLAS = 2;

private List<Animal>[] myAnimals = (List<Animal>[]) new List<?>[3]; // You know the size.

List<Duck> ducks = new ArrayList<>();
List<Cow> cows = new ArrayList<>();
List<Gorilla> gorillas = new ArrayList<>();

myAnimals[DUCKS] = ducks;
myAnimals[COWS] = cows;
myAnimals[GORILLAS] = gorillas;
```

This solution is the fastest you can implement, but you have to care about your index values in order to get this working. As @xenteros said you are making a contract that you must follow. But with the constants `DUCK`, `COWS` and `GORILLAS` it is really easy ;)

**Edit**: a better approach would be to use an `Enum` as @Sergey Rybalkin suggests to manage the Animals's types, so if they grow highly up and you get like 400 types of animals, using an `Enum` would be more flexible. It would be something like:

```
private enum Animals {
    DUCKS,
    COWS,
    GORILLAS; 
}

private List<Animal>[] myAnimals = (List<Animal>[]) new List<?>[Animals.values().length]; // You can get the length of your enum.

List<Duck> ducks = new ArrayList<>();
List<Cow> cows = new ArrayList<>();
List<Gorilla> gorillas = new ArrayList<>();

myAnimals[Animals.DUCKS.ordinal()] = ducks;
myAnimals[Animals.COWS.ordinal()] = cows;
myAnimals[Animals.GORILLAS.ordinal()] = gorillas;
```

`ordinal` method gives you the value position where the enum constant has been defined. In this case, `Animal.DUCKS.ordinal()` gives you 0, `Animal.COWS.ordinal()` gives you 1... More information in the [java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html)

> Returns the ordinal of this enumeration constant (its position in its
>   enum declaration, where the initial constant is assigned an ordinal of
>   zero).

Comment: `HashMap` and `Array` have the say data access complexity.

Comment: @xenteros For big data not. `Hashmap` has **average** O(1) as you said, and `Array` has **always** O(1)

Comment: Making number of constants is nonsense. `Enum` is good. Moreover `enum` has `length`.

Comment: @SergeyRybalkin True! I added your suggestion